# Why is $A \leq_T \bar{A}$?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, reductions

I know there's some easy proof for this, but why is $A \leq_T \bar{A}$ ? ... Suppose that $\bar{A}$ is c.e. and could loop, does this mean that the oracle $TM$ $M^{\bar{A}}$ could also loop?

But shouldn't $\leq_T$ mean that $M^{\bar{A}}$ be decidable?

Comment: Oracles don't loop, that's the point of oracles: they always give you the correct answer.

Comment: oh right, would be handy in my exam

Answer (score 2):

A language $A$ Turing-reduces to $\overline{A}$ since a Turing machine with an $\overline{A}$-oracle can compute $A$. On input $x$, it determines whether $x \in \overline{A}$ using the oracle, and then outputs the reverse answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your misunderstanding is in the definition of an oracle. An oracle is a hypothetical device that answers the question "Is string $x$ in language $L$?" in a single computational step. It doesn't matter whether or not an actual Turing machine could answer that question; the oracle is *defined* to answer it, and answer it immediately.

Whether or not such a device can exist in the physical universe is irrelevant to the question of reducibility. It's relevant to the question of whether the reduction is practically usable, but that's a separate issue.